# image not properly rendering in cycles render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing

[image]

While rendering in Blender Cycles images are not properly rendering, but in the
render preview option switching solid shading mode to rendering its clearly coming.

I don't know what's happening in image rendering.

[image]

Switching the preview option to solid to rendering mode...

Comment: I'm assuming the included image is the result that you don't want. You say the rendered preview looks better, so could you include a screenshot of that as well? Or possibly upload the .blend to [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and edit your question to include the link to the file.

Comment: Are all of the layers with the other objects included in the rendered layer? Please look through the possible causes for issues like this on this link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up.